# Aptana 3 crashes on Slackware 13.1 because of SWT error

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I have problem with Aptana 3 running on a Linux Slackware 13.1. I've actualized java to 6.29 but without any luck. Aptana tells me that it is an SWT error and it is recommended to close a workbench. When I'm ignoring this message it crashes after sometime. Any ideas?

```
An internal error has occurred.
No more handlesNative code library failed to load. (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
/home/kfedorczyk/Downloads/aptana3/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_1.0.0.129549059/os/linux/x86/libcefjni.so:
/home/kfedorczyk/Downloads/aptana3/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_1.0.0.129549059/os/linux/x86/libcefjni.so: undefined symbol: gzopen64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, try to install jpeg6-devel package. I'm running Pardus Linux, maybe in Slackware the package has other name.